# Stars and days rating algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I'm working on algorithm to rate posts by stars. One star price is equal to one day price. The question is how to calculate stars price for specific amount of days.

Algorithm for buying stars is:
(amount of stars) * (days) * price (lets say 1$).

In the beginning post has 0 stars and 0 days. Owner of post can buy any amount of stars for any amount of days, except for zero values. Owner can buy unlimited amount of times. Stars and days always sum up.

**Examples:**
If owner buys 1 star for 20 days, price is: 1 * 20 * 1$ = 20$
If owner wants to increase amount of stars, by 20, he needs to buy 20 stars for 1 day. So it becomes like this: 20 * 1 * 1$ = 20$
Right now in total post has 21 days and 21 star.

**Problem:**
If the user buys two times like in the example, he will pay in total 40$ for 21 star and 21 day. If user would buy it in single buy, he would pay 21 * 21 * 1$ = 441$

We need to make so that however the user buys stars or days, the sum would always be the same if he would buy everything in single buy.

**Solutions:**
To check how many stars user already have, and add up on hes next buy. For example:
First buy: 20 * 1 * 1$ = 20$
Second buy: 1 + 20 (from first buy) * 20 * 1$ = 420$

So in conclusion i have 21 star for 21 days for 420$ + 20$ = 440$, when if i would buy in single buy, it would be 421$.

Comment: I'm guessing that you sum all the days and all the stars, and thats's the problem? By seperating the transactions and what type of star it is, this problem will not occur. A 21day star is not the same as 20 stars for one day.. The number of days the star is valid for should probably determin if you sum them up or not?